# twisted.internet.interfaces.ITransport.write: Expected 0 positional arguments

Tags: python-3.x, twisted, pyright, zope.interface

This is my code:

```py
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet.interfaces import ITransport

class AbcProtocol(LineReceiver):
    transport: ITransport

    def lineReceived(self, line: bytes) -> None:
        self.transport.write(line)
```

Then, I got a warning from pyright:
`8 col 34-44 error| [Pyright reportGeneralTypeIssues] Expected 0 positional arguments [E]`
I think, Pyright think the first parameter is just self and I shouldn't pass the `self` parameter.
Is there a way to let pyright understand the first parameter isn't `self`?
Or is there something wrong with my understanding?

---

The `ITransport` like this:

```
class ITransport(Interface):
    def write(data: bytes) -> None: ...
```

The first parameter is not `self`.
In examples of [zope.interface document](https://zopeinterface.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README.html), the first parameter is not `self`.

---

I expected pyright doesn't generate any warning and understand first parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pyright has declined to implement support for zope.interface](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/999) so it will not be able to understand code written using Zope interfaces.

Comment: Ok.... is there any workaround?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to Mypy and enable [the `mypy-zope` plugin](https://github.com/Shoobx/mypy-zope) that supports zope.interface.